# Scalatra asyncPost multiple unit tests mixed up requests

Tags: scala, unit-testing, future, scalatra

I'm new to scala so I might not be clear with the issue I'm facing, I might not be including all the details needed to identify the issue. I'll do my best to clarify.

I'm converting a `post` scalatra endpoint to `asyncPost` and converting `Await.result`s to `Future`s. The unit tests that used to pass are now failing intermittently: **a test is executed with request from another test**. When I remove all tests and run each test individually they all pass. At this point my hypothesis is that the requests are being mixed up across unit tests. I'm not sure if this is an issue with the code or unit test setup.

This is a production code so there is a lot of logic that I can't fit here, I try to remove everything and keep what I think is relevant.

Actual code:

```
class Endpoints(...)
  extends ...
    with ABC_ExecutionContext
    with FutureSupport {

  protected implicit def executor = executionContext

  val myEndpoint: Route = asyncPost("/endpoint/", operation(queryGroup)) {
    setTransactionName(":post /endpoint")
    
    new AsyncResult { val is = {
      for {
        ...
        out <- doSomethingWithRequest() // implicit request is passed, returns a Future
        ...
        response <- doSomething(out) // returns a Future
      } yield response
    }}
  }
}
```

Tests:

```
class EndpointsSpec
  extends MockitoSugar
    with JsonFormats
    with ... {

  "POST /endpoint on Endpoints" should {
    "should work for request A" in {
      post("/endpoint/",
        write(mockRequestA).getBytes(),
        Map("user-id" -> "12345")) {
        body must_== """something A"""
        status must_== 200
      }
    }

    "should work for request B" in {
      post("/endpoint/",
        write(mockRequestB).getBytes(),
        Map("user-id" -> "12345")) {
        body must_== """something B"""
        status must_== 200
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I also tried to create a context per unit test

```
class EndpointsSpec
  extends MockitoSugar
    with JsonFormats
    with ... {

  "POST /endpoint on Endpoints" should {
    "should work for request A" in {
      val context: HystrixRequestContext = HystrixRequestContext.initializeContext
      try {
        post("/endpoint/",
          write(mockRequestA).getBytes(),
          Map("user-id" -> "12345")) {
          body must_== """something A"""
          status must_== 200
        }
      } finally {
        context.shutdown()
      }
    }

    "should work for request B" in {
      val context: HystrixRequestContext = HystrixRequestContext.initializeContext
      try {
        post("/endpoint/",
          write(mockRequestB).getBytes(),
          Map("user-id" -> "12345")) {
          body must_== """something B"""
          status must_== 200
        }
      } finally {
        context.shutdown()
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The issue might be with something I have omitted, let me know and I can add more details before making sample code too complicate

Extra info:

- Test framework: specs2 + mockito

Comment: not srue how scalatra works, but sounds like you are using ScalaTest. You have a section in the official docs that explain how to do [Asynchronous testing](https://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/async_testing). If that is not enough, add details such as what testing framework you are using, what assertions error you are getting.

Comment: Thanks @GastónSchabas. Added test framework: specs2 + mockito. Also added what I mean with tests failing: a test is executed with request from another test. I had looked into the link you shared. It seems like that's for the case that you are testing logic with futures and you don't want the tests to get blocked on it. I'll still try to get it working with it.

Comment: My bad. I thought you were using scalatest. What's the error that you are getting during the test? an assertion error? timeout? deadlock? It's not clear what is the error that you are getting. I tried to give a quick look at scalatra docs and couldn't find any info about how to work with async request neither how to test them. Just the integration with akka, but they don't use `asyncPost`, only `post` or `get` with `AsyncResult`. Are you following some tutorial or reading an specific book?

Comment: That was it, needed to switch from `asyncPost` to `post`. Not sure which tutorial I used, definitely not the right one haha. Feel free to suggest this as the answer and I'll mark it.

Comment: you said that you are new to scala. I'm wondering why you started with this framework. Looks like the latest release ([2.8.0](https://github.com/scalatra/scalatra/tree/v2.8.0)) was published on Jul 24, 2021. If you check the following comits, most of them are to update dependency libraries and no new feature was added. The [latest closed issue](https://github.com/scalatra/scalatra/issues/1439) was on Oct 15, 2022. To be honest, I haven't heard about a company using it to build a new project

Comment: I'm new to it, but our company has existing code in scala and I'm making improvements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have experience with [Scalatra](https://scalatra.org/guides/2.8/) neither with [Specs2](https://etorreborre.github.io/specs2/). Just giving a quick look to the docs of `Scalatra` and how to work with [async requests](https://scalatra.org/guides/2.8/async/akka.html), just using `get`, `post` or the one you need without the `async` prefxi should work. From the docs here you have an example

```
class MyAppServlet extends ScalatraServlet with FutureSupport {
  get("/"){
    new AsyncResult { val is =
      Future {
        // Add async logic here
        // ...
      }
    }
  }
}
```